# Best way to associate an entity JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I have a manytoone relationship between two entities and i want to know if there's a better option to save using an existing id, for example, in the example below, should i send a company id inside json or first create a Role and the using PUT update the Role with company Id. Or maybe inside the Controller find the company entity and then set in the new Role entity and after that, save it. How to proceed in this case?

```
@Entity
data class Role(
        val name: String = "",

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
        val company: Company,

        val type: RoleType,
        val description: String = ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `company`field of Role is mandatory **(Not Null)** then you need to create first Company so that you can link with ID or Name or whatever as foreign key. Then you first create a Company and later a Role related to it.

```
{
   "name" : "Role Name - 1",
   "company" : 1,   // or "Company-"
   "type" : "Type - 1",   
   "description" : "This a test description"
}
```

Comment: I see .. that's the question, how to link with foreign key? maybe when receive the company Id = 1 should i need to search for a Company entity with id = 1? or there's a way to JPA to understand the company Id and save it correctly?